# Is there a way to have an webview on android where I can inject css before the page is loading?

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

I need to have a webview where I inject CSS to a webpage before it is loaded so that the injected css is applied to the loading page itself. On iOS webviews this is a native feature, but as far as I know, there is no feature like that in the android native webview.

I tried using flutters inAppWebview for that, but according to their doc at https://inappwebview.dev/docs/javascript/user-scripts/ they can't provide that feature because of the same reason and therefore the behavior isn't guaranteed.

Is there some alternative webview out there that provides this kind of feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your CSS code in the `public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` method then it will be applied before the page load is finished.
It will help you to prevent users to sees the actual webpage before your CSS gets applied.

**below is the full code**

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    String url = getString(R.string.blogURL);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

`WebViewClient` class code

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

         //if in the website used any javascript to interact with CSS then also add in this method, otherwise remove it from this method.
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var h1 = document.getElementById('et_mobile_nav_menu').style.visibility='hidden'; " +
                "})()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var h1 = document.getElementById('et_mobile_nav_menu').style.visibility='hidden'; " +
                "})()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        Toast.makeText(BlogActivity.this, "Something is wrong while loading blog. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

You can modify or stylish web pages with your own custom CSS style sheet in Android web-view. To do that, we have just a CSS file and a few lines of code needed.

like~

```
@Override 
   public void onPageFinished(String URL, WebView view) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, URL);

   // Inject CSS when page is done loading
      injectCSS();
     
   });

  // Load a web
    webl.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
}



// Inject CSS method: read style.css from assets folder
// Append stylesheet to document head
    private void injectCSS() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("black.css");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            webl.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                    "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                    "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                    "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                    // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                    "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                    "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                    "})()");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
```

Hope it will helpful

reference - https://www.programmersought.com/article/54381014286/

Comment: But onPageFinished get's only triggered when the page is loaded, right? So the user sees the actual webpage and then my css gets applied. E.g. if I hide an element in my css, it gets loaded and then disappears. Or if I change the text color, the old color gets shown and then overwritten.

What I am looking for is applying the css before that, so that the user directly sees the css changes.

Comment: then you can use custom AlertBox instead of using CSS... You can get many stylish templates for your alert box or you can also use CSS on your project but just convert "CSS to SVG" and then use it as loading stuff. 

reference - https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I know alert boxes only as a user dialog, so sadly I don't really understand how to use it to solve my problem yet. I want e.g. to call "google.com" in a webview and change the background to red, so that the user never sees the original white background, even during loading. How would I do that by using an AlertBox?

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I'm really stuck at this point and don't really understand how I can achieve my goals using the AlertBox. Can you give me a few more hints?